# Сравнение списков из JSON отправка нужного значения по id

Tags: java, android

Есть такой JSON `info{"id":"25","name":"Черновицкая область"}`
Я его распарсил и область  вставлятся в autocomplettextview

```
 Log.d(TAG,"AutoComplete jsonArray"+ jsonArray);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject info = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d(TAG,"AutoComplete info"+ info);
                    String id=info.getString("id");
                    String name=info.getString("name");
                    list_name.add(name+id);
                }
                Log.d(TAG,"List"+ list_name);
                String[] region = list_name.toArray(new String[0]);
                String[] id = list_id.toArray(new String[0]);
                Log.d(TAG,"Array"+Arrays.toString(region));
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AutoComplete.this,
                        R.layout.autocompletephone,region);
                autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Как сравнить и отправить НЕ область

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("region", autocompletextview.getText().toString());
```

а id  в зависимости от выбранной области

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("id", ?????);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) есть конструктор, принимающий `List<T>`, поэтому вот это вот:

```
String[] region = list_name.toArray(new String[0]);
String[] id = list_id.toArray(new String[0]);
```

излишне.

После получения данных Вы сразу же можете разместить их в `HashMap` (а лучше всего сразу добавлять их туда):

```
HashMap<String, String> regions = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i<list_name.size(); i++) {
    regions.put(list_name.get(i), list_id.get(i));
}
```

Далее, Вы можете получить значение по ключу:

```
String id = regions.get(autocompletextview.getText().toString());
```

И далее его обрабатывать.

PS. Обратите внимание на code style: в Java, для именования переменных, [рекомендован](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.7-local-variable-names) lowerCamelCase.